# Overpass query: Search range of integers not working for 2 digit numbers

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to search for all admin levels with the values between 7 to 11 using the following query (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Dn5):

```
(relation[admin_level~"^[7-11]$"]["wikidata"]({{bbox}});
```

The error says:

> static error: Invalid regular expression: "^[7-11]$"

Surprisingly a search query with `^[3-6]$` works perfectly fine. So it seems to be related to the 2 digit number.

Does anybody know how to improve this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expressions for numeric comparisons is no longer needed since release 0.7.55 and discouraged these days. Instead you can use numeric comparisons like described in the following blog post: http://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/numbers.html

For your example, the respective query should look as follows:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];
relation[admin_level]
        (if:is_number(t["admin_level"]) &&
                      t["admin_level"] >= 7 && 
                      t["admin_level"] <= 11)
         ["wikidata"]({{bbox}});
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But your query also found admin levels smaller than 7. I changed it a bit and it seems to work now:
`
[out:json][timeout:60];
relation[admin_level]
        (if:(t["admin_level"] >= 7 && 
             t["admin_level"] <= 11))
         ["wikidata"]({{bbox}});
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
`

Comment: You're right, there was an issue with parentheses after is_number(....)... I fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

The `[a-b]` notation matches a single character in a range, for example `[a-z]` matching lower case letters.

What you can do for a small range of integers is to spell them out as alternatives. This might work:

```
//not working (admin level from 7 to 11)
[out:json][timeout:60];
(relation[admin_level~"^(7|8|9|10|11)$"]["wikidata"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

but is obviously tedious if you have 100 levels.

There's some info on regexping numeric ranges here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. Just 11 levels, anyway. So the solution is great. This also seems to work:

`(relation[admin_level~"[7891011]"]["wikidata"]({{bbox}});`

Comment: I'm not convinced by that - the area in your link in your Q doesnt seem to have any 10 or 11 in it, but if I zoom out a bit I can find some, but the [7891011] doesn't find it properly.

Comment: Around Potsdam is an admin_level=11. And the query seems to be able to find it (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Dnc)

Comment: Compare http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Dnd which matches ^[1011]$ - it finds nothing and http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Dne which matches ^10$ and finds areas in the same bounding box.

Comment: Once you add a 9 at the beginning (i.e. `^[91011]$`) it is working again. Anyway, thanks for your support.

Comment: Adding the 9 finds the level 9 areas (click to see) - it will also find level 1 or level 0 areas if they exist, but doesn't find level 10 or 11 areas.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `admin_level~"[91011]"` without the ^ and $

Comment: That will match any level with one or more 0s, 1s, or 9s in it - so level 0, level 1, level 21, level 932 and so on. If that catches 9, 10, and 11 and no other levels (eg there is no level 12 in the data) then okay, but its the same as `[019]`. The correct way (ok, one correct way) to match *only* 9, 10, and 11 is `^(9|10|11)$` between the quote marks.

Comment: Using regular expressions is really the outdated way of doing things, you should use numeric comparisons instead. See http://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/numbers.html